# p-dropdown css behaves differently

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, primeng

my primefaces dropdowns are displayed correctly on chrome (2nd screenshot), but not on firefox (1st screenshot):
[image]

[image]

here's a snippet of my code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group">
                <label>xx</label>
                <p-dropdown placeholder="xxx"
                 (...)
                </p-dropdown>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group">
                <label>xxx</label>
                <p-dropdown placeholder="xxx">
                (...)
                </p-dropdown>
            </div>
       </div>
```

**Edit:**

Rendered HTML is https://pastebin.com/i0XTbWEq

Comment: `p-dropdown` is from... PrimeFaces I think? You may want to update your tags. Providing a [mre] is a nice thing to do so that people can understand what's happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was caused by primeng css, I had to override `width: -webkit-fill-available;` with `width: 100%;`. that solved the issue.